# Constructor to simulate hand of cards

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to create a constructor to simulate a hand of cards in a trading card game. Initially the hand should be empty upon creation, so that I may add cards later, once the object has been constructed. Can anyone tell me why the following code doesn't work and how I should approach this problem?

```
private ArrayList<Card> cardsInHand;

public Hand() {
  cardsInHand = ArrayList<Card>();
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `new`.

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"

Comment: You just gave a chance to clutter the site :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to initialize your `ArrayList<Card>` in your constructor you must use the keyword `new` before calling its constructor.

For instance:

```
cardsInHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

In a similar way, when you'll initialize your own `Hand` object, you'll call it with the following code:

```
Hand hand = new Hand();
```

Here is some documentation on Java [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
cardsInHand = ArrayList<Card>();
```

should be

```
cardsInHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instanciate the Arraylist by doing:

```
cardsInHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

You missed "new".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new before ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<Card> cardsInHand;

public Hand() {
  cardsInHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing an ArrayList, so just add the keyword "new".

```
private ArrayList<Card> cardsInHand;

public Hand(){
    cardsInHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you forget to code `new` operator. Java is Object-oriented language.

```
cardsInHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```